# set the size of figure legend in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, figure

everyone. I am using plot function in R studio. Below is my plot. As you can see, the figure legend box is too big, I want to set it smaller. I have tried to modify same parameters, but it didn't work. 
my code is:

```
legend("topleft", legend=names(attr(colcode, "table")), 
       fill=attr(colcode, "palette"), cex=0.6,bg = "white", text.width = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I edited your question to include the image. The answer spaces below your question are only for answers, not for comments, just so you know.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified `text.width = 1` which on your graph is the entire width of the graph. It will look OK if you reduce text.width. Try

```
legend("topleft", legend=names(attr(colcode, "table")), 
       fill=attr(colcode, "palette"), cex=0.6,bg = "white", text.width = 0.1)
```

You may need to reduce it even more.